# scaling a circle on mouseover using Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Could you please help me in this.

I am drawing a circle using Raphael.On mousehover the circle should zoomin and zoomout(scaling).

I am able to increase the size of circle easily,but i want some effect in between increasing the size of the circle. It should increase like elastically.

I want to develop that animation using Raphel.
can you please help me

This is the code i have written :

```
smallCircles[0].hover(function () { 
    smallCircles[0].animate({ fill: 'rgb(231,88,88)', opacity: 0.95, r: 55,r:45,r:55, 'stroke-width': 0 }, 100); 
  },
  function () { 
    smallCircles[0].animate({ fill: 'rgb(240,153,153)', opacity: 0.8, r: 35, 'stroke-width': 0 }, 300); 
});
```

Thanks,
Nagarjuna

Comment: The link doesn't work and I have no idea what you're talking about... Does your circle increase to a new diameter immediately, and you want the increase to be animated (smooth)?

Comment: yes,what i want is after placing the mouse on circle ,the circle size should increase with animation.
For Example:
Initially the radius of the Circle is 20mm.
after placing the mouse the radius should increase to 40mm.
Here what i need is after placing the mouse over the circle the radius should increase to 40mm then again it should decrease to 30mm then again 40mm then agter 30mm .Finally it shud draw the circle with 40mm..
Its completely like a elastic type of decreasing and increasing the size of the circle..
Iam implementing this with Raphael.js library..

Thanks,
Nagarjuna

Comment: Hi Bane
I did it finally
see the example here http://jsfiddle.net/ryWH3/74/
Thanks for your help

Comment: ah, nice...you should answer your own question with this :)

Comment: Oh, I see you came right by adding the easing parameter before I posted my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the built in easing modifiers?

I haven't tested the below, but perhaps it works. I added 'elastic' as the `easing` parameter for the `animate` method

```
smallCircles[0].hover(function () { 
    smallCircles[0].animate({ fill: 'rgb(231,88,88)', opacity: 0.95, r: 55,r:45,r:55, 'stroke-width': 0 }, 100, 'elastic'); 
  },
  function () { 
     smallCircles[0].animate({ fill: 'rgb(240,153,153)', opacity: 0.8, r: 35, 'stroke-width': 0 }, 300, 'elastic'); 
});
```